# UV Coords include adjacent Sprite

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

My sprites are part of a uniformed spritesheet, and each sprite is drawn with extra pixels on the top and right side of the quad. They seem to be from adjacent sprites. Here's how I defined the UV Coords:

```
ratio = spriteCountX / spriteCountY;

UVcoords.x = (float)(index % spriteCountX) / (float)spriteCountX;
size.x = ratio / (float)spriteCountX;

UVcoords.y = (float)(index / spriteCountX) / (float)spriteCountY;
size.y = 1.0f / (float)spriteCountY;
```

And the Vertex Data: (x,y,z positions plus the UV coords for each vertex)

```
vertexData[] = {  -size.x / 2,    size.y / 2,   0,  UVcoords.x,                     UVcoords.y,
                  -size.x / 2,    -size.y / 2,  0,  UVcoords.x,                     UVcoords.y + size.y,
                  size.x / 2,     -size.y / 2,  0,  UVcoords.x + (size.x / ratio),  UVcoords.y + size.y,
                  size.x / 2,     size.y / 2,   0,  UVcoords.x + (size.x / ratio),  UVcoords.y}
```

The Texture filters are defined as:

```
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
```

I've tried adding `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`with no luck:

```
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, 
                   GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, 
                   GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Here's an illustration of what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem named ["texture or pixel bleeding"](http://www.realitymod.com/forum/f189-modding-tutorials/90244-pixel-bleeding.html) or "texture atlas edge artifacts". It is due to the rounding of coordinates, that are floating values in the interval [0..1].

The only solution to reduce drastically artifacts is to introduce some pixel padding between sprites. I suggest you two alternative:

- Start from [here](https://andenginetmxtiledmapartifactfixer.googlecode.com/hg/src/org/anddev/andengine/entity/layer/tiled/tmx/TMXTiledMapArtifactFixer.java) to create your utility to modify your existing texture atlas.
- Use an sprite sheet editor like [this](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) to create sprite sheet texture with padding between sprites of atlas.